# Can one Pasted Items in PDF at the same location on the page?

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat

I am filling out a PDF with some info (Names, Dates, etc.) that often need to have multiple pages with the same info added.
When I copy the comments or items in acrobat (Or Foxit) from page one and paste them onto page 2, they get pasted a bunch below and to the right of where they were copied from and I need to move them manually back into place.

Is there a way to copy objects or annotations and paste them in the same location on a future page?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use comments to fill out a form.

If the author did not care to make it fillable, do it yourself. Then duplicate the repetitive fields, keeping their name the same. When you fill out, every field with the same name will also have the same value (meaning contents).

Comment: That is one solution. Thanks! If rather just copy and paste and be done with it though